# Use offline recognition when online

Tags: android, voice-recognition, connectivity

Due to client restrictions, I need to use offline voice recognition even when I'm online.

As far as I know, offline recognition is not accesible via code, but the system itself uses the offline one if there is no internet connection, using the online one if we have connection. Am I right about this? If I am right, is there any way of "trick" the system to think he is offline in order to use the offline recognition?

Regards

Comment: What is "voice recognition"? Google's service? A 3rd party library? A custom `SpeechRecognizer` implementation? Need more details.

Comment: The default SpeechRecognizer, which uses an offline mode if you dont have internet and if you previously downloaded your default language package

Comment: Hmm. On my gNex running 4.2.2 it uses offline by default, and only seems to go online if it can't figure something out. That's with both a simple `SpeechRecognizer` and the Google Now app. It's probably up to whatever `RecognizerService` is set to default on the system.

Comment: So if it has the language available offline it will be used by default, right? Any idea about refusing to use SpeechRecognizer if the language is not available? I tried to check languages available but couldnt get any list

Comment: That's the way it works on mine, anyway. As for languages... I haven't tried it, but `ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS` looks promising, which *should* return a Bundle containing `EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES`.

Comment: I tried the ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS, however it return a list with every language available to download I think, anyway I had 3 languages installed and the list had like 40 languages

Comment: Yea, like I said, haven't tried that one. It's really a separate question though, and you probably won't get a good answer here in the comments. I'd recommend asking a new question about that if you can't find a good answer elsewhere.